# jQuery flip speed

Tags: jquery

Below is the code I made for flipping between two `div`,

How can I control the speed of the fliping action?

Here is the code:

#### HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="go">FLIP</button>
<div class="container">
    <div class="page1">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque euismod mauris       metus, ac consectetur felis. Cras consectetur, est vel malesuada faucibus, ligula enim suscipit elit, ut ornare quam urna quis felis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
    </div>
    <div class="page2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis interdum, odio vel       condimentum varius, nibh nunc 
    </div>
</div>
```

#### JS:

```
$('.container').click(function() {
    var page1 = $('.page1');
    var page2 = $('.page2');
    var toHide = page1.is(':visible') ? page1 : page2;
    var toShow = page2.is(':visible') ? page1 : page2;

    toHide.removeClass('flip in').addClass('flip out').hide();
    toShow.removeClass('flip out').addClass('flip in').show();
});​
```

Comment: There is no flip code to see. If you want to hide and show pages with specific milisecs time then use .show(200) and .hide(200)

Comment: the problem is once I add any number inside hide() and show() the fill movement looks weird.

Comment: Plz post the filiping stuff code to see.

Comment: I posted them on my question,here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/lakario/VPjX9/

Answer (score 0):

You can pass options to [`hide`](http://api.jqueryui.com/hide/) and [`show`](http://api.jqueryui.com/show/):

```
.hide({duration: 500 /* ms */});
.show({duration: 500 /* ms */});
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of the hide/show functions corresponds to the duration in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `hide()` and `show()` methods of jQuery, like in this fiddle, take a look:

http://jsfiddle.net/YqhpS/26/

Answer (score 0):

Do you use CSS3 transforms for the flip effect? Then you can specify the transition duration like this:
`transition: <property> <duration> <timing-function> <delay>`

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be faster or slower change in the css here:

```
.flip.out {
   -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) scale(.9);
   -webkit-animation-name: flipouttoleft;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 250ms;        // here
   -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg) scale(.9);
   -moz-animation-name: flipouttoleft;
   -moz-animation-duration: 250ms;           // here
}
.flip.in {
   -webkit-animation-name: flipintoright;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 525ms;       // here
   -moz-animation-name: flipintoright;
   -moz-animation-duration: 525ms;          // here
}
```

check this one if this helps.

Comment: That's Great! This would be greater if you either upvote or accept it as answer or even both, if you could.

Answer (score 0):

I have just done something like that. I downloaded the jquery flip-plugin from CDN. Then I made a div with class 'photo' for alle my photographs, and each photo got a div class 'front' and 'back' with their content. Main CSS should go to the main div 'photo'. Explained on e.g. Github, there are others as well.
The js code is simple. You can add all kinds of attributes to the plugin, also speed.
`<script>
$(function(){
    $(".flip").flip({ 
        trigger: 'click',
        speed: 1000
           });
});
</script>`

I see that your question is rather old. Perhaps all this did not yet exist when you asked it.